# How to get Drivers for Lenovo Essential E4325

Tags: drivers, software-installation

I have Windows 8 installed on my Lenovo E4325 Laptop... I want to install Ubuntu as a dual boot... Please anyone let me know do i need to install any additional drivers or are the drivers comes with the OS after installing the Ubuntu version...If Yes, How?

Answer (score 0):

On Linux, for mainstream hardware that has been on the market for some months, there's almost never need to install any drivers.
I'd recommend you run a live system from thumbdrive oder DVD and test everything. Your Ubuntu installation medium should allow this. Connect to your wifi, test ethernet, the usb ports, the touch pad and I guess it should work.
Check out the support for your external hardware like printers or scanners.